# How to create a popup after password reset using input submit form?

Tags: html

I am trying to achieve this without much JS but not sure if I can do it.
    I have a password reset page and when the user clicks "done", then I would        like that dialogue box to disappear and be replaced with a a popup/dialogue box that replaces the other, and says "We have sent you an email with instructions on how to reset your password....Please check your email, etc."
 *It needs to appear after the data is submitted. As you can see, I can't seem to make this work. Any thoughts/direction would be much appreciated:

```
<form method="post">
<a href="#openModal"><input type="submit" name="email" value="Continue"></a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close"></a>
 <p>We have sent you an email with instructions on how to reset your password.</p>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It would help if you provided more code and a better description of what's going on. All you have here is an HTML form element. So, no, I can't see what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function sent() {
alert("We have sent you an email with instructions on how to reset your   password.");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<a href="#openModal">
<input type="submit" name="email" value="Continue" onclick="sent()">
</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close"></a>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will work as I actually have other input fields/buttons in this form that are apart of the "reset pswd" dialogue box...so that will affect the other input fields - which is what I don't want.

I simply want the reset password box replaced with a box that says "an email has sent....", when you click on Submit.

Comment: onclick can be used the same way inside your button tag

Comment: Makes sense! Won't work though...hmmmm...will keep at it tho. Thanks
I simply want the reset password box replaced with a box that says "an email has sent....", when you click on Submit.

Comment: OK I have this:

<a href="#openModal"><input type="submit" name="email" value="Continue" onsubmit="sent()"></a>

with this:

<script type="text/javascript">
sent() { alert("We have sent you an email with instructions on how to reset your password."); }
</script>

Still nothing :(

Comment: then use the method i gave you and add onclick="sent()" inside your submit button tag. have the alert say what you want it to say. that should work.

Comment: Nope-sorry.
Could it be getting confused with the script I have for the submit button?

<?php 

 /********************************************
 Called when user presses the forget password link.
 *********************************************/
 // Call the reset password function. 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $return=User::resetPassword($_POST['email']);
  echo $return;
 }

?>

Comment: put the script in your head and add the word function in front of sent function. sorry. that works.

Comment: OK, did that but still nothing-it just reloads the page

Comment: check out what i did up top it worked for me. don't forget doctype and html open and closing tag.

Comment: @ kfreeman04208
Thanks and your code looks good...but although I can see your button, its doing nothing, just page reloads. 
Thanks so much for your help but I think I need some sleep...will try tomorrow :)

Comment: The code works try to copy paste if its not working for you